# C - 2d array print crashing after initialization

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I wanted to try some C basics, as I've not seen this language for several years. So, I've written a very simple program, which allocates a 2D-array and then I wanted to initialize it with some value and print it.

The problem is - when I initialize elements `[0][0]` or `[0][1]`, then the program crashes, when I try to print the 4th row.

Do you know, where's the problem?

---

#### My code (MWE)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {

    int size = 5;
    int** array_2d;

    array_2d = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
    if(array_2d==NULL) exit(-1);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
        array_2d[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*size);;
        printf("Allocated %d. column.\n", i);
    }

    int row, column;
    for ( row = 0; row < size; row++) {
        for( column = 0; column < size; column++) printf("%d ", array_2d[row][column]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    array_2d[0][0] = 1;
    printf("%d\n", array_2d[4][0]);

    return 0;
}
```

---

#### Error

```
Allocated 0. column.
Allocated 1. column.
Allocated 2. column.
Allocated 3. column.
Allocated 4. column.
-2002258752 21956 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 

Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

Comment: `int** array_2d;` <- misnomer, this is a pointer to a(n array of) pointer...

Comment: `array_2d = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int)*size);` --> `array_2d = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*size);`

Comment: therefore this is wrong as well: `array_2d = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int)*size);` .. the element type would be `int *` here.

Comment: suggest to make this readable and more failsafe like this: `array_2d = malloc(size * sizeof(*array_2d))` <- cast is unnecessary and by dereferencing your identifier, you can be *sure* to have the correct type for your `sizeof()` always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a problem:

```
array_2d = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
```

You want to create an array of *pointers* to `int`, but you only allocate memory for an array of `int`.

On a platform where `sizeof(int) != sizeof(int *)` (like a typical 64-bit system) you will not allocate enough memory and then go out of bounds and have *undefined behavior*.

The simple solution is to use the variable itself when allocating:

```
array_2d = malloc(sizeof *array_2d * size);
```

By dereferencing `array_2d` for the `sizeof` operator, it will be equal to `sizeof(int*)`, and you will allocate memory enough for `size` number of pointers to `int`.

Comment: It might be worth noting that this is only a "*2d array*" in an abstract, conceptual sense, but not in the terms of C.

Comment: I was close to correcting the first line, and then I read the whole answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access 5th element in the following line while you have allocated memory for 4 elements starting from 0 to 3. In C, array indexes start from 0 and goes onward. 0 is 1st, 1 is 2nd and so on.

```
printf("%d\n", array_2d[4][0]);
```

Replace it with

```
printf("%d\n", array_2d[3][0]);
```